# How to compute $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1}\mathrm dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Could you explain to me, with details, how to compute this integral, find its principal value?

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1}\mathrm dx$$

$f(z) =\frac{\sqrt{z}}{z^2-1} = \frac{z}{z^{1/2} (z^2-1)}$

It has singularities on the real line, so I need to integrate this function over a curve made of segment $[0, 1- \varepsilon] \cup $ semicircle with endpoints $1- \varepsilon, \ 1+ \varepsilon \cup$ segment $[1+ \varepsilon, R]$ and we link $R$ and $0$ with a big semicircle .

The integral over the big semicircle vanishes.

Integral over the small semicircle, centered in $1$ tends to $i \pi Res_1f$ as its radius tends to $0$.

Could you tell me how to calculate this put this together and find this integral?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to solve this integral a certain way?

Comment: Are you asked to use contour integration?

Comment: The integral is divergent. So, I assume you want to calculate the principal value?

Comment: Yes, I am supposed to find its principal value. Sorry, I forgot to mention that in my question.

Comment: @Don I'm pretty sure I can show you how to calculate the integral, if that helps. I don't know anything about principal values though.

Comment: Hint: For every $u\gt1$, use the change of variable $x\to1/x$ in the part $(0,1/u)$ of the integral on $(0,1/u)\cup(u,+\infty)$ to transform this into a computable integral on $(u,+\infty)$, then consider the limit $u\to1$.

Comment: In general, for $0<k<n$ we have $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^n}dx=\frac\pi n~\cot\bigg(k~\frac\pi n\bigg)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integral as stated does not converge.  On the other hand, its Cauchy principal value exists and may be computed using the residue theorem.

Consider the integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\sqrt{z}}{z^2-1} $$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour of outer radius $R$ and inner radius $\epsilon$, with semicircular detours of radius $\epsilon$ into the upper half plane at $z=1$.  The contour integral is then

$$\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} dx \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1}+  i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\sqrt{1+\epsilon e^{i \phi}}}{\left (1+\epsilon e^{i \phi} \right )^2-1} \\  + \int_{1+\epsilon}^R dx \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1} + i R \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{\sqrt{R} e^{i \theta/2}}{R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}-1} \\ + \int_{R}^{1+\epsilon} dx \frac{e^{i \pi} \sqrt{x}}{x^2-1} + i \epsilon \int_{2\pi}^{\pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\sqrt{e^{i 2 \pi}+\epsilon e^{i \phi}}}{\left (1+\epsilon e^{i \phi} \right )^2-1} \\ + \int_{1-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} dx \frac{e^{i \pi} \sqrt{x}}{x^2-1} + i \epsilon\int_{2 \pi}^0 d\phi \frac{\sqrt{\epsilon} e^{i \phi/2}}{\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}-1}$$

As $R \to \infty$, the magnitude of the fourth integral vanishes as $R^{-1/2}$.  As $\epsilon \to 0$, each of the second integral contributes a factor of $-i \pi/2$, the sixth integral contributes a factor of $i \pi/2$ and the eighth integral vanishes as $\epsilon^{3/2}$.  Also, the first, third, fifth, and seventh integrals add to the Cauchy principal value of an integral.  Thus, the contour integral is equal to

$$2 PV \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1} $$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the pole $z=e^{i \pi}$ inside $C$.  Thus,

$$PV \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1} = i \pi \frac{e^{i \pi/2}}{2 e^{i \pi}} = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Comment: The first integral is due to integrating along the segment $[\varepsilon, 1- \varepsilon]$ along the real line. Next, we integrate along the little semicircle till we touch the real line, then we integrate along the real line from $1- \varepsilon$ to $R$, then along the big semicircle, here  $z = Re^{i \varphi}, \ 0 \le \varphi \le \pi$

Comment: Could you tell me where the other integrals come from?

Comment: @Don: we double back along the real line after traversing the bug semicircle.  Along the doubling back, $z=x e^{i 2 \pi}$.

Comment: $e^{2 \pi i} = 1$, isn't that right, I must have misread that.

Comment: @Don: yes, but since we have a square root, we have to deal with different branches.  Setting $z=x e^{i 2 \pi}$ is an expression of those branches.

Comment: Oh, ok I see. So after the $4$th integral we end up in $\varepsilon$ on the real line. Then we go to $R$ and go along the real line to $1 + \varepsilon$ then down along the lower semicircle with radius $\varepsilon$, then again along the real line from $1 - \varepsilon$ to $\epsilon$ and shouldn't we go from $\pi$ to $2 \pi$, because then we go along the lower big semicircle with radius $R$, right?

Comment: @Don: thanks, you caught a mistake in the derivation.

Comment: you're welcome, but now I do not see why, while integrating over the bid semicircles, the limits of integration are $0, 2 \pi$, that's a whole turn for $z = Re^{i \phi}$.

Comment: @Don: It's a big circle, not semicircle.  Look up keyhole contour in wiki or on the site.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28IV.29_.E2.80.93_branch_cuts Is it this curve, on the right with an additional $\varepsilon$ hole in $z=1$?

Comment: @Don: yes, sort of.  We have bumps above and below $z=1$.

Comment: Ok, last question - why do we begin with integrating $\int_{\varepsilon}^{1- \varepsilon}$ and omit the first hole? Ok, I see that we don't. The last integral covers that.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\delta_1>0,\delta_2<1$ real numbers close to zero and one, respectively, and I=$(\delta_1,\delta_2)\cup(\delta_2^{-1},\delta_1^{-1})$.
We have:
$$ \int_{I}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1}\,dx = \int_{\delta_1}^{\delta_2}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1}\,dx +\int_{\delta_1}^{\delta_2}\frac{\sqrt{1/x}}{1-x^2}\,dx = \int_{\delta_1}^{\delta_2}\frac{1}{x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}}\frac{dx}{x}$$
and by setting $x=u^2$:
$$ \int_{I}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-1}\,dx = 2\int_{\sqrt{\delta_1}}^{\sqrt{\delta_2}}\frac{du}{u^2+1}, $$
so, by letting $\delta_1\to 0,\delta_2\to 1$, we get that the principal value of the original integral is given by:
$$ 2\arctan(1) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large a}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\mbox{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\root{x}}{x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$.

---

We'll consider the $\ds{\root{z}}$-branch cut:
$$
\root{z}=\verts{z}\exp\pars{\half\,{\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ic}\,,\qquad
0 < \,{\rm Arg}\pars{z} < 2\pi\,,\quad z \not= 0
$$
We'll perform an integration over a key-hole contour $\ds{\gamma}$ which takes care of the above branch-cut:
$$
\oint_{\gamma}\frac{\root{z}}{z^{2} - 1}\,\dd z
=2\pi\ic\bracks{\verts{\expo{\pi\ic}}^{1/2}\exp\pars{\half\,\pi\ic}\,\frac{1}{2\expo{\pi\ic}}}=\pi\tag{1}
$$
The contribution from a 'big arc' of radius $\ds{R}$ goes as $\ds{R^{-1/2}}$
when $\ds{R \to \infty}$ while the contribution of a 'small arc' of radius $\ds{\epsilon}$, around the origin, goes as $\ds{\epsilon^{3/2}}$ when $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
\oint_{\gamma}\frac{\root{z}}{z^{2} - 1}\,\dd z
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{\root{x}\expo{0\ic/2}}{\pars{x - 1 + \ic 0^{+}}\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
+\int_{\infty}^{0}
\frac{\root{x}\expo{2\pi\ic/2}}{\pars{x - 1 - \ic 0^{+}}\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\root{x}\bracks{%
\frac{1}{\pars{x - 1 + \ic 0^{+}}\pars{x + 1}}
+\frac{1}{\pars{x - 1 - \ic 0^{+}}\pars{x + 1}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=2\,\mbox{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\root{x}}{x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x\tag{2}
\end{align}
With $\pars{1}$ and $\pars{2}$:
$$
\color{#66f}{\large\mbox{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\root{x}}{x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x}
=\color{#66f}{\large\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach. Recalling the Mellin transform

> $$ F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x)dx.$$

We have the Mellin of our function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ is given by

> $$ F(s) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \cot(\pi s/2). $$

So our integral can be evaluated as

> $$ I =\lim_{s\to 3/2}F(s) = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Comment: Perhaps it seems odd that you are taking, as a given, a result more general than the result that needed proving.  Also, I am not sure if the Mellin transform as you define it is a Cauchy principal value by default; the integral by which $F(s)$ is defined does not exist otherwise.

Comment: BTW I understand your frustration with the downvotes.  I took a look and see that your postings have been downvoted in a suspicious pattern lately.  This happened to me last year and I did get some relief by contacting the Stack Exchange staff.